# Is it ok to use the web view to render non web content web developing for iOS4

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-graphics, ios

I'm just learning the iPhone SDK and about drawing with `CG` and `UIKit` and whilst I can see the usefulness for building interfaces as a web developer I can't help but think it would be a hell of a lot easy if I could layout content (ie heading, paragraphs, lists, images) with html and css

presumably this is possible using the web view and injecting custom html and css into it
is there any reason this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's not only ok, it's pretty common. I recommend having a good reason to do so before using this method. "Because it's easier than using the UIKit framework" is not a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Go for it. It's one of the tools at your disposal, so don't be shy about using it.